# AWS EC2 Server - source ~/.bashrc

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and springboot. Here i am trying to deploy my spring application **first time in AWS** using UBUNTU but getting command not found message as in below screen shot. Some one please guide me

Screenshot:

Comment: What does your `.bashrc` contain?

Comment: I am new to this. How to check the contents of bashrc?

Comment: `cat ~/.bashrc`, although you should be careful about running commands given to you by random strangers online.

Comment: I am following a course on udemy.Instructor command is working but mine is throwing above error.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-30:~$ cat ~ /.bashrc
cat: /home/ubuntu: Is a directory
cat: /.bashrc: No such file or directory

Comment: I am getting output as above

Comment: Without the space, that was my typo.

Comment: It contains properties like jdbcurl, username and passwords

Comment: It also seems to contain a syntax error, at least based on the message you're getting on the console.

Comment: @NarenReddy There seems to be a space between your "/" and "bashrc". I suppose the empty space should not be there. Additionally, in case there is not bashrc there, you can create a new bashrc and put the contents there.

Comment: @AmanSrivastava There is no space between "/" and "bashrc".Can you please tell me how to create new bashrc

Comment: use the vim editor, i.e., the vi command.